# Computing a "cheap" upper bound on the norm of the solution to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, computational-complexity, systems-of-equations

Consider the linear system $A x = b$, where $A$ is an invertible, $n \times n$, real matrix. I would like to compute a "cheap" upper bound on the (p-)norm of the solution; i.e. $\|x\|_p$. One can, of course, solve the system and get the exact value in $O(n^3)$ time. Can we get an upper bound on $\|x\|_p$ any quicker than this?

Comment: The operator norm of $A$ gives you an easy lower bound.  Upper bound?  Not sure yet.

Comment: What would really help is an upper bound to $\|A^{-1}\|_p$, but I'm not sure if a nice one exists.

Comment: Yes, in many cases one can compute the induced norm $\|A\|_p$ more quickly (e.g. in $O(n^2)$ time). That, if I'm not mistaken, however, can only be used to compute a lower bound.

Comment: We could use the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of $A$

Comment: I'm not familiar with any algorithm that can compute the condition number faster than $O(n^3)$. That, of course, does not mean that such an algorithm doesn't exist :)

Comment: I don't think one exists, at least for $p=2$. I think knowing a tight upper bound is equivalent to knowing the condition number.  So, if we want something faster, we'll need a worse upper bound...

Comment: I'm fine with (somewhat) loose upper bounds. I just want to be able to compute a reasonable bound without having to solve the system.

Comment: [An algorithm like this might help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/condest.html).  It might give you an underestimate, though.

Comment: Also, searching for an "upper bound for the condition number" turns up a few papers, which can help if you're willing to dive that deep.

Comment: It is *easy* to bound/estimate $\|A\|$, it is *hard* though to do the same with $A^{-1}$. If it turned out to be easy it would probably be a disaster :-) ... There are several techniques besides SVD to estimate condition numbers, all of them are $O(n^3)$ though for dense matrices. It can be cheaper if $A$ is *really very special* (e.g., diagonal or *strongly* diagonally dominant), is sparse (e.g., using incremental estimation in sparse LU factorisation) or structured (e.g., Toeplitz).